# android-Show permission in the application analyzer if access is not given in the manifest

Tags: android, permissions

**Problem** - I removed the
`android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` access from the manifest file in Android as I do not want to use it.

I even deleted the code completely and there is no word called `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in the whole project.

But when I put the app in the analyzer, it shows `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` access :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem myself and I share it.
In the desired tag, you must add a command

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    tools:node="remove" />
```